# Ambiguous reference with local NuGet package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget-package

After referencing a locally built NuGet package for diagnostics (clone/build of the current repo - on my machine it's built as "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-t002a46b59",) in an untouched RC2 ASP.NET Web App, NuGet automatically starts to restore packages.

In doing so it seems that an ambiguous reference is created as my Program.cs is unable to distinguish the version of .UseContentRoot I want to use.

[image]

I don't have enough familiarity with the project.json and NuGet relationship to determine what the root cause is.

Am I missing a step in the process or is there something more fundamental causing the issue?

My project.json is as follows:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-JamieTest-ffeafaa8-e549-4ce5-89f2-69089954bd81",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-t002a46b59",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "gcServer": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the dependencies on your locally built `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics`? The reason for it is most likely that your locally built `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics` pulls an outdated package (i.e. a `Microsoft.AspNet.*` one). So you end up with 2 versions of the same assembly (with 2 different names) where both have the same Extension method registered. This is the reason for the message. Check up referenced libraries dependencies in the dependency tree view in solution explorer

Comment: Spot on @Tseng - I managed to identify the root cause. Posting an answer for it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing the [aspnet/Diagnostics](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/) repository includes a [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/pull/757/commits/057bcb43acd694d890ff750f0265d699a0801394) which refactors the location of several Hosting based extension methods.

Unfortunately, the ***File -> New Project*** output from RC2 is looking at the previous location for the extension methods. As my locally built NuGet package and the RC2 output use differing implementation, the compiler is unable to determine which one is correct.

I wasn't paricuarly bothered which implementation was used as long as they were the same, and the path of least resistance was to change my locally built NuGet package to use the **RC2** version of **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions**.

Whilst this corrected the immediate issue I then came across two others at runtime, whereby the included dependency injection failed to load required types.

In total, I had to make three changes to my Diagnostics project.json file in order for my locally built NuGet package to load and be debuggable within Visual Studio:

[image]